# My tidy narrow spinner expands to the ugly plain screen, when activated (continued)

Tags: android, width, spinner

As I am now allowed to post images, so I accomplish my question by images and code.

My 5 spinners, as seen on the first screenshot, represent only short numbers. There is no problem to form their width in .xml file. But when they are activated, they expands to into a full width of the screen, making it´s appearance ugly, as seen in the second screenshot. I use the standard code from the SDK tutorial to populate the spinners. I experimented with simple_spinner_dropdown_item and simple_spinner_item. Both have the same functionality, but slightly different graphics. Unfortunately, I found nowhere published how to acces/modify these 2 blocks, so I cannot change their width, color, textsize, atc. Is here somebody having some hints how to cope with this problem?
This is a standard code of spinner (=SDK tutorial), (only one spinner is showed):

```
Spinner s1_weight = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.s1_weight);//Reference to "s1_weight"  in main.xml, registered in R.id.
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter_weight = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
        this, R.array.Weight_array_id, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter_weight.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
s1_weight.setAdapter(adapter_weight);
s1_weight.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {  //Register a callback to be invoked when an item in this AdapterView has been selected.
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,  //Callback method to be invoked when an item in this view has been selected
            int arg2, long arg3) {
            myCalc();}
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
});
```

This is my .xml file (only one spinner is showed):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <TextView
        android:text="@string/txtWeight"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".6"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" 
        android:textStyle="bold">
    </TextView>
    <Spinner
        android:entries="@array/Weight_array_id"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/s1_weight">
    </Spinner>
</LinearLayout>
```

And these are my screenshots:

[image: Tidy narrow spinner, when not activated]

[image: One spinner activated, results in ugly screen]

Comment: I substituted the simple_spinner_item by my custom_spiner_item and can now control the gravity and text color of the drop-down-menu. But the width is still out of my control.